# How connect to a database at 9 O'clock in android?

Tags: android, android-service

In android i'm trying to access a database at a predefined time. In my application it runs a simple android service and inside that i want to check the external database(MySQL) at a specific time. I'm using a java web service to access the database.

```
public class DBService extends Service {

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://dbconnectivity.com/test/";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "test";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://dbconnectivity.com";
private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8089/DB_Connectivity/services/SqlConnectivity?wsdl";
String str;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    //Toast.makeText(this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);          
    request.addProperty("time",0);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

        SoapPrimitive s = response;
        str = s.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Test "+str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

How to do this task ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at AlarmManager class or check [this](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129) tutorial and at specified time run http poll to mysql server (you will need some php script to return result from MySQL, as android does not support direct DB connection)